# Autosize an SVG?

Tags: css, svg

Here is a [code demo](http://jsfiddle.net/y59MR/1/)

I have a SVG with an unknown height. I can figure it out after I load in json and use javascript+math but is there any css I can use to dynamically size it?

css:

```
svg {
  width: 500px;
  height: 9000px;
}
.tabme {
  border:3px solid red;
  height: 200px;
   overflow:scroll;
}
```

html:

```
<div class="tabme">
  <div id="Chart">
    <div class="chartbody" />
    <svg>
      <rect width="190" y="0" height="16" x="175" />
      <rect width="190" y="20" height="16" x="175" />
      <rect width="190" y="40" height="16" x="175" />
      <rect width="190" y="60" height="16" x="175" />
      <rect width="190" y="80" height="16" x="175" />
      <rect width="190" y="100" height="16" x="175" />
      <rect width="190" y="120" height="16" x="175" />
      <rect width="190" y="140" height="16" x="175" />
      <rect width="190" y="160" height="16" x="175" />
      <rect width="190" y="180" height="16" x="175" />
      <rect width="190" y="200" height="16" x="175" />
      <rect width="190" y="220" height="16" x="175" />
      <rect width="190" y="240" height="16" x="175" />
      <rect width="190" y="260" height="16" x="175" />
      <rect width="190" y="280" height="16" x="175" />
      <rect width="190" y="300" height="16" x="175" />
    </svg>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: svg { height: 100%; width: auto } may be ? And it will work like an image and will be 200px height, and saves it ratio..

Comment: @Flops: auto doesn't work. Also i wanted height

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If the SVG element does not have any width and height attributes, then the width/height should be [calculated according to the CSS specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#inline-replaced-width), as pointed out by Robert Longson.  However, those values will not reflect the proper dimensions of the SVG's content. You can find out the proper dimensions and placement using `getBBox()`:

```js
// Javascript to run after document load
var svg = document.getElementsByTagName("svg")[0];
var bbox = svg.getBBox();
svg.setAttribute("width", bbox.width + "px");
svg.setAttribute("height", bbox.height + "px");
svg.setAttribute("viewBox", `${bbox.x} ${bbox.y} ${bbox.width} ${bbox.height}`);
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" style="background-color: red">
  <rect x="30" y="40" width="50" height="60"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: There are rules which define the width/height to use in http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#inline-replaced-width you end up with 300px x 150px if there's nothing better.

Comment: @RobertLongson: Interesting, thanks for that info! My impression was that results were inconsistent, but maybe my memory is simply inaccurate. I'll change the answer to incorporate that info.

Comment: Results are inconsistent as not all UAs have implemented the rules correctly yet.

Answer (score 3):

An alternative is to do similar to the above JS but set `viewBox` (note, not `viewbox`!) instead of `width` and `height` from JS with values from the `getBBox()` call.  Then use `preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet"` or similar.

```
var svg = document.getElementById("x1");
svg.setAttribute("viewBox", "0 0 32 18.4");
```

https://jsfiddle.net/t88pLgbb/4/

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by Thomas's answer, here's how I did it:

```js
if (true) {
  let svg = document.getElementById("bleh");
  let bb = svg.getBBox();
  svg.setAttribute("width", bb.width);
  svg.setAttribute("height", bb.height);
  svg.setAttribute("transform",
    "translate(-" + bb.width / 2 + ",-" + bb.height / 2 + ") \
    scale(" + 600 / bb.width + "," + 250 / bb.height + ") \
    translate(" + bb.width / 2 + "," + bb.height / 2 + ")");
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<div style="width: 600px; height: 250px; border: 1px solid blue;">
  <svg id="bleh">
    <path d="M0 0 T100 400 T500 500 T800 200 T0 0" fill="purple" opacity="0.8" />
    <path d="M0 0 L100 400 L500 500 L800 200 L0 0" fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="2" />
  </svg>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Goal: try to auto-fit the entire SVG graph into the div of size 600*250.

Basically what I did was get the width and height of the SVG after it was formed, translate it 50% left and up, scale it according to the ratio of width and height difference between the 600*250 div and the SVG graph dimensions, and then translate it back 50% right and down. This way it stayed centered while I scaled it. (It doesn't seem to like actual percentages this way...)

Comment: I think it's better to use the `viewBox` attribute (as suggested by @GufNZ) instead of transforms. I updated my answer to include that.