# SVG Clipping Issue (HTML, JS, JQUERY, CSS)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, svg

I am trying to incorporate a preloader within my site and I would like the splash screen's loading bar to be in the shape of a custom logo. I have successfully created a clipping svg on text and images before, so I don't believe that this is where the problem is (see my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/roxy_p/g30ymLke/9/)).

I just need the loading bar's containing svg to clip the loading bar div in the shape of the inline svg.

I have included my code.

Thanks.

```js
(function($) {
 var items = new Array(),
  errors = new Array(),
  onComplete = function() {},
  current = 0;
 
 var jpreOptions = {
  splashVPos: '35%',
  loaderVPos: '75%',
  splashID: '#jpreContent',
  showSplash: true,
  showPercentage: false,
  autoClose: true,
  onetimeLoad: false,
  debugMode: false,
  splashFunction: function() {}
 }
 
 //cookie
 var getCookie = function() {
  if( jpreOptions.onetimeLoad ) {
   var cookies = document.cookie.split('; ');
   for (var i = 0, parts; (parts = cookies[i] && cookies[i].split('=')); i++) {
    if ((parts.shift()) === "jpreLoader") {
     return (parts.join('='));
    }
   }
   return false;
  } else {
   return false;
  }
  
 }
 var setCookie = function(expires) {
  if( jpreOptions.onetimeLoad ) {
   var exdate = new Date();
   exdate.setDate( exdate.getDate() + expires );
   var c_value = ((expires==null) ? "" : "expires=" + exdate.toUTCString());
   document.cookie="jpreLoader=loaded; " + c_value;
  }
 }
 
 //create jpreLoader UI
 var createContainer = function() {
  
  jOverlay = $('<div></div>')
  .attr('id', 'jpreOverlay')
  .css({
   position: "fixed",
   top: 0,
   left: 0,
   width: '100%',
   height: '100%',
   zIndex: 9999999
  })
  .appendTo('body');
  
  jLoader = $('<svg></svg>')
  .attr('id', 'jpreLoader')
  .appendTo(jOverlay);
  
  var posWidth = $(window).width() - $(jLoader).width();
  $(jLoader).css({
   position: 'absolute',
   top: jpreOptions.loaderVPos,
   left: Math.round((50 / $(window).width()) * posWidth) + '%'
  });
  
  jBar = $('<div></div>')
  .attr('id', 'jpreBar')
  .css({
   width: '0%',
   height: '100%'
  })
  .appendTo(jLoader);
 }
 
 //get all images from css and <img> tag
 var getImages = function(element) {
  $(element).find('*:not(script)').each(function() {
   var url = "";

   if ($(this).css('background-image').indexOf('none') == -1 && $(this).css('background-image').indexOf('-gradient') == -1) {
    url = $(this).css('background-image');
    if(url.indexOf('url') != -1) {
     var temp = url.match(/url\((.*?)\)/);
     url = temp[1].replace(/\"/g, '');
    }
   } else if ($(this).get(0).nodeName.toLowerCase() == 'img' && typeof($(this).attr('src')) != 'undefined') {
    url = $(this).attr('src');
   }
   
   if (url.length > 0) {
    items.push(url);
   }
  });
 }
 
 //create preloaded image
 var preloading = function() {
  for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
   if(loadImg(items[i]));
  }
 }
 var loadImg = function(url) {
  var imgLoad = new Image();
  $(imgLoad)
  .load(function() {
   completeLoading();
  })
  .error(function() {
   errors.push($(this).attr('src'));
   completeLoading();
  })
  .attr('src', url);
 }
 
 //update progress bar once image loaded
 var completeLoading = function() {
  current++;

  var per = Math.round((current / items.length) * 100);
  $(jBar).stop().animate({
   width: per + '%'
  }, 500, 'linear');
  
  if(jpreOptions.showPercentage) {
   $(jPer).text(per+"%");
  }
  
  //if all images loaded
  if(current >= items.length) {
   current = items.length;
   setCookie(); //create cookie
   
   if(jpreOptions.showPercentage) {
    $(jPer).text("100%");
   }
   
   //fire debug mode
   if (jpreOptions.debugMode) {
    var error = debug();
   }
   
   
   //max progress bar
   $(jBar).stop().animate({
    width: '100%'
   }, 500, 'linear', function() {
    //autoclose on
    if( jpreOptions.autoClose )
     loadComplete();
   }); 
  } 
 }
 
 //triggered when all images are loaded
 var loadComplete = function() {
  $(jOverlay).fadeOut(800, function() {
   $(jOverlay).remove();
   onComplete(); //callback function
  });
 }
 
 //debug mode
 var debug = function() {
  if(errors.length > 0) {
   var str = 'ERROR - IMAGE FILES MISSING!!!\n\r'
   str += errors.length + ' image files cound not be found. \n\r'; 
   str += 'Please check your image paths and filenames:\n\r';
   for (var i = 0; i < errors.length; i++) {
    str += '- ' + errors[i] + '\n\r';
   }
   return true;
  } else {
   return false;
  }
 }
 
 $.fn.jpreLoader = function(options, callback) {
        if(options) {
            $.extend(jpreOptions, options );
        }
  if(typeof callback == 'function') {
   onComplete = callback;
  }
  
  //show preloader once JS loaded
  $('body').css({
   'display': 'block'
  });
  
  return this.each(function() {
   if( !(getCookie()) ) {
    createContainer();
    getImages(this);
    preloading();
   }
   else { //onetime load / cookie is set
    $(jpreOptions.splashID).remove();
    onComplete();
   }
  });
    };

})(jQuery);
```

```css
body{
 display:none;
}
#jpreOverlay {
 background-color: rgba(000, 000, 000, 0.87);
}

#jpreLoader{
 width:300px;
 height:300px;
   
}
#jpreBar {
 background-size:30px 30px;
 -moz-background-size:30px 30px;
 -webkit-background-size:30px 30px;
 -o-background-size:30px 30px;
   filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(
      startColorstr='#33ffffff',
      endColorstr='#33000000',
      GradientType=0 );
 background-color:#E07300;
 clip-path: url(#clipping);
 -webkit-clip-path: url(#clipping);
    -moz-clip-path: url(#clipping);
    -o-clip-path: url(#clipping);
 position: absolute;
}

@-webkit-keyframes progress {
  from {
    background-position: 0 0;
  }
  to {
    background-position: -60px -60px;
  }
}
@-moz-keyframes progress {
  from {
    background-position: 0 0;
  }
  to {
    background-position: -60px -60px;
  }
}
@-ms-keyframes progress {
  from {
    background-position: 0 0;
  }
  to {
    background-position: -60px -60px;
  }
}
@-o-keyframes progress {
  from {
    background-position: 0 0;
  }
  to {
    background-position: -60px -60px;
  }
}
@keyframes progress {
  from {
    background-position: 0 0;
  }
  to {
    background-position: -60px -60px;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>jPreLoader v2 - A jQuery preloader for Website</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jpreloader.css" />
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
<script src="js/jpreloader.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://www.inwebson.com/wp-content/themes/inwebson2/favicon.ico" />
<link rel="canonical" href="http://www.inwebson.com/demo/jpreloader-v2/" />
</head>

<body>

<section id="wrapper">
 <div class="wrapper-inner">
 <hgroup>
  <h2>jPreLoader v2</h2>
  <h3>A loading screen to preload images using jQuery</h3>
 </hgroup>
 <div class="container">
 <ul id="set1" class="holder current">
  <li><img src="http://sphotos-b.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-snc6/181548_153793501342544_153515891370305_259700_7241508_n.jpg" /></li>
  <li><img src="http://sphotos-b.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-snc6/196528_158118380910056_153515891370305_283882_234528_n.jpg" /></li>
  <li><img src="http://sphotos-b.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-snc6/196556_159931940728700_153515891370305_293999_6261181_n.jpg" /></li>
  <li><img src="http://sphotos-b.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-ash4/205687_165495210172373_153515891370305_326385_1869822_n.jpg" /></li>
  <li><img src="http://sphotos-b.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-snc6/205600_167760236612537_153515891370305_338177_2160812_n.jpg" /></li>
  <li><img src="http://sphotos-b.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-snc6/248150_174306909291203_153515891370305_374445_3774819_n.jpg" /></li>
  <li><img src="http://sphotos-b.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-snc6/228343_171546129567281_153515891370305_358267_5126730_n.jpg" /></li>
  <li><img src="http://sphotos-b.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-ash4/249232_174478049274089_153515891370305_375652_2662480_n.jpg" /></li>
  <li><img src="http://sphotos-b.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-snc6/268903_186646411390586_153515891370305_435046_34596_n.jpg" /></li>
  <div class=clearfix></div>
 </ul>
 <ul id="set2" class="holder">
  <li><div id="li1"></div></li>
  <li><div id="li2"></div></li>
  <li><div id="li3"></div></li>
  <li><div id="li4"></div></li>
  <li><div id="li5"></div></li>
  <li><div id="li6"></div></li>
  <li><div id="li7"></div></li>
  <li><div id="li8"></div></li>
  <li><div id="li9"></div></li>
 </ul>
 <div class="clearfix"></div>
 </div>
 <div class="description txtright">
  Images by <a href="http://www.facebook.com/MichaelShawPhotography">Mike Shaw</a>, Cheshire UK based photographer.
 </div>
 </div>
 
</section>

<!-- This section is for Splash Screen -->
<section id="jSplash">
 <section class="selected">
     <svg width="82" height="82" id="jpreLoader" clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox">
  <defs>
    <clipPath id="clipping">
      <path stroke-opacity="0" fill-opacity="1" stroke-width="0" stroke="none" fill="#282525" d="M244,121.9L250.5,123.2C239.2,127.9 228.9,132.6 221.4,138.2L212.2,138.2L212.2,147.3C212.2,157.7 224.6,172.8 233.2,182.2L238.1,182.2C253.2,200.4 299.6,221.8 320.6,232.1C309.8,235.3 290.9,234.3 281.2,230.2L258.6,220.8C251,219.6 241.9,218.9 235.4,221.5C217.6,213.3 198.7,207 205.2,202.3C180.4,191.6 168.6,184.1 162.6,176.5L136.7,191.6C133.5,190 127,190.7 123.8,192.6L84.4,214.9C62.9,216.1 35.9,243.4 9.5,243.4C8.4,243.4 7.9,243.1 7.9,242.8C7.9,241.2 16.5,238.1 18.7,236.5C19.2,236.2 19.2,235.9 19.7,235.6L43.5,222.4L42.4,218.6L23.5,228.7C25.1,221.8 23.5,213.3 28.9,204.8L46.7,195.1C48.9,190.7 52.6,186.9 57.5,182.8L65,185L94.2,169C100.6,165.2 111.9,159.6 111.4,152.7C121.6,147.3 130.3,142.3 137.3,136.7C141.6,136.3 145.9,135.7 148.6,133.8C148.6,133.2 147.5,132.3 147.5,131.6C130.3,96.5 128.7,61.6 150.8,26.4C155.1,24.6 162.1,22 165.3,24.6L156.1,41.5C163.2,38.4 167.5,30.5 172.3,24.6C203.1,27.1 203.1,39.3 219.8,39.9L225.7,46.5C216.5,57.5 210.6,74.2 210.1,82.3L206.8,87L211.1,88.6C245.6,68.2 286.6,41.2 319.5,23.6L328.1,23.6L328.1,28C333.5,26.4 338.9,19.2 352.9,20.5L348.1,25.5C372.9,28.6 389.6,36.5 389.6,41.8C389.6,43.4 389.1,45 386.4,46.2L244,121.9M46.7,216.1L48.3,219.3C53.7,217.7 55.9,214.5 55.9,211.7L46.7,216.1M65,181.3L61.3,180.3C66.1,176.9 72,173.4 78,169.9L81.7,172.1L65,181.3M85,170.3L81.2,168.1C84.4,166.5 87.1,164.9 90.4,163.3L90.4,167.1L85,170.3M237.6,138.2L230,138.2L242.9,131.3L247.3,132.3L237.6,138.2M253.2,228.7L240.3,223.3C246.2,221.8 253.7,223.6 262.4,227.7L253.2,228.7z"></path>
    </clipPath>
  </defs>
</svg>
  <h2>jPreLoader v2</h2>
  <strong>A loading screen to preload images using jQuery</strong>
 </section>
</section>
<!-- End of Splash Screen -->

<script>
$(document).ready( function() {
 var timer; //timer for splash screen
 
 //calling jPreLoader
 $('body').jpreLoader({
  splashID: "#jSplash",
  loaderVPos: '30%',
  autoClose: false,
  splashFunction: function() {  
   //passing Splash Screen script to jPreLoader
   $('#jSplash').children('section').not('.selected').hide();
   $('#jSplash').hide().fadeIn(800);
   
   timer = setInterval(function() {
    splashRotator();
   }, 4000);
  },
 });
 
 //create splash screen animation
 function splashRotator(){
  var cur = $('#jSplash').children('.selected');
  var next = $(cur).next();
  
  if($(next).length != 0) {
   $(next).addClass('selected');
  } else {
   $('#jSplash').children('section:first-child').addClass('selected');
   next = $('#jSplash').children('section:first-child');
  }
   
  $(cur).removeClass('selected').fadeOut(800, function() {
   $(next).fadeIn(800);
  });
 }
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This isn't an answer, but maybe it can be helpful, because this is also an issue here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23560038/html5-inline-svg-autocrop-whitespace.

Comment: Have You considered making a transparent png with orange logo, put it in DIV, and crop it using div? in that case you only need to change the div width to make the logo appear. Why SVG?

Comment: Thanks Jacek. After endless searching, I have resorted to using an image of the logo as my preloader. Appreciate the help.

Comment: No problem. I think that this is the easiest way to achieve a nice effect. However, the question is still not answered, and maybe there are other applications of this techniqu, which can not be substituted using simple images. Maybe someone will enlighten us ;). Best regards!

Comment: It was certainly the easiest fix but I found that the contained content was being placed beyond the container's viewport thus clipping it and not revealing the contained information (or the progress bar in this case), so finding a way to reposition the contained content to be relative to the container would be the fix but my project was pressed for time so I went for the easiest fix. When I have a moment to fix it I will post the answer. Thanks so much though! (: Regards.